# Azure Service Bus connection string results in CloudStorageAccount.Parse error

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string

The following call

```
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(<connection-string>);
```

returns this error:

> "No valid combination of account information found."

with the connection string copied directly from the CONNECTION STRING–PRIMARY KEY field on the Azure service Bus Access Policies -> Policy blade, which looks like this:

Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxx;SharedAccessKey=xxx;EntityPath=xxx

I need CloudQueueClient and CloudQueue instances to do queue manipulation. 
Am I missing something obvious, or is there another way to initialise CloudStorageAccount?

Update: the following syntax allows me to add a new queue using the service level (not queue level) credentials, but I'm not sure how I get from here to a CloudQueue or CloudQueueClient instance.

```
var queueNamespace = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(
     "Endpoint=sb://<service-account>.servicebus.windows.net/;
     SharedAccessKeyName=sharedaccess;
     SharedAccessKey=xxx");
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to use storage client library for Service Bus resources. `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` is the client library for Azure Storage. Queues in Azure Storage are not a Service Bus Queues.

For Service Bus queues you would need to use its client library that you can install via Nuget from https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/.

Once you do that, you should be able to create a `NamespaceManager` using the following code:

```
var manager = Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
```

and then you will be able to perform operations on your Service Bus Queues.

You may find this link useful as well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues/.

Comment: Awesome! Were you able to perform operations on your queues in your Service Bus account or you need further help?