# Azure service bus AddMessage returns 401

Tags: c#, azure

The following AddMessage call (code borrowed from another post) fails with "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

```
var queue = new CloudQueueClient(
     new Uri("https://<service-account>.servicebus.windows.net/"), 
     new StorageCredentials("access1", "xxx")).GetQueueReference("queue1");

queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("Hello"));
```

Where xxx is the 44-character PRIMARY KEY copied from Azure's configuration screen. It doesn't contain any 'special' characters. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Using the service level Service Access Policy credentials gives the same 401 error.

This is the [Azure policy configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNPvd.png) for my service-account.

(I did try another approach, but hit another snag [service bus connection-string problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648656))

Comment: Rob, you're doing it all wrong IMHO! Please see my answer to your other question.

Comment: I think I'm off track here, mixing StorageCredentials and CloudQueueClient. Is there an equivalent syntax for service bus?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it. Please ensure that you have added reference to `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` in your project.

```
            var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, queueName);
```

Now you can perform operations on that queue using `queueClient` like adding messages, reading messages etc.

To perform operations at the Service Bus level like creating queue, you would need to get an instance of `NamespaceManager` like the following:

```
        var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
        manager.CreateQueue(queue);
```

I would highly recommend reading this guide to get started with Service Bus: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues/.